# I want Elmah just send log errors on production server iis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, smtp, elmah

Hey Im using Elmah to log my MVC razor errors, and I use SMTP email configuration to get notified via email, the problem is that elma is sending emails throw my local debuggin, and I dont want it, because I just want to log the error when its trigger only on production server iis, how can I do that.

I know that I can errase the smtp line in the web.config  but I make lot of changes, I would like to have it dynamic.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer from this page:

[ELMAH: Can you set it up to email errors only remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914463/elmah-can-you-set-it-up-to-email-errors-only-remotely)

`I found a solution which is to use config transforms with VS 2010. I remove the tag from my base web.config then added it to my Web.Qa.Config and Web.Release.Config with transform tags. When I publish, it allows the remote machines to send out the emails while they are supressed locally. I will end up going this route, but I will let your answer get a few more upvotes and mark it as answer based on that.`

Answer (score 0):

With web.config transform:

And this in your web.production.config, with the correct parameters

> ```
> <errorMail from="tfscdf54@gmail.com"
>                 to="jose.alvarez54@free.fr"
>                 cc="cdf.bts.iris@live.fr"
>                 subject="CDF 54 ELMAH Error"
>                 async="true"
>                 smtpPort="587"
>                 useSsl="true"
>                 smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com"
>                 userName="tfscdf54@gmail.com"
>                 password="YOURPASS" xdt:Transform="Insert" />   </elmah>
> ```

Comment: yes but it throw me this exception :namespace prefix 'xdt' is not defined web.config Im trying to get the namespace but I cant find it

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<errorMail  xdt:Transform="InsertAfter(/configuration/elmah)"
        from="from@test.com"
        to="to@test.com"
        subject="..."
        />
```